# Using a function using loop elements

Tags: r

I want to loop through a list of elements and use them in a function. Here is a partial code, from a t-test in jamovi package.

```
j = c("K1", "K2")

for (i in j) {  
  temp1 <- jmv::ttestIS(
    formula = i ~ T1,
    data = data1,
    vars = i,
    students = FALSE,
    eqv = TRUE)
    
  temp1
}
```

I get the error that the argument `i` is not in the dataset. I suppose it's because the function sees `i` as itself and not `K1`. Any ideas how to access the loop elements in the function?

ps. I can provide a reproducible code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as.formula()`.  However, please note that you are overwriting `temp1` for each iteration of `j` here; was that your intention?

```
for (i in j) {  
  formula = as.formula(paste(i,"~T1"))
  temp1 <- jmv::ttestIS(
    formula = formula,
    data = data1,
    students = FALSE,
    eqv = TRUE)
  
  temp1
}
```

Comment: `as.formula` is correct but I don’t see how using `get(i)` would work here.

Comment: sorry, is vars supposed to be a character string of variable names?  my mistake. If so could just leave as `vars=i`

Comment: With `vars=i`, I get this error `Argument 'vars' contains 'i' which is not present in the dataset`.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `vars`, since you are using a formula to express the dependent variables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
for (i in j)
```

use

```
for (in in 1:length(j))
```